# Custom `def` macro for Clojure(Script) DSL

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I want to write a DSL including a `defx` that wraps the native `def` and invokes a constructor:

```
(defmacro defx [name & args]
  `(def ~name (ctor ~@args)))
```

When I reference a value defined by a call to `defx` (e.g. `(defx somex 1 2 3) (println somex)`) ClojureScript complains with `WARNING: Use of undeclared Var somex`. It works fine at runtime, so how do I get rid of the warning?

**Update:** I was requiring the macro with `:refer [defx]` which is supported in cljs since 1.9.198, but apparently as of 1.9.293 there are still some shortcomings. Requiring with the explicit `:refer-macros` fixes the warnings.